# Monitor network traffic usage per user by terminal?

Tags: networking, monitor, traffic

Can you offer me some tools with which i can monitor traffic usage per user in WiFi/Ethernet network per user? And also will be good if i can see PC's name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `nethogs` is useful for you. the output is:
[image]

install with: `sudo apt-get install nethogs`